# my dog won't eat kibble and tried to bite my roommate

Tags: dogs, behavior, feeding, aggression

my dog is a 2 years old shiba inu, male. sometimes (maybe once a month), he won't finish his meal, maybe only eat half of it, and then just look at the bowl or laying next to it. I used to just put the kibble away and he become very nervous and bites his toy, once i put the kibble away and he becomes fine.

yesterday i was out of town for business, and my roommate fed my dog kibble. he was doing this again. and bites my roommate when he tries to get up from the sofa.

why my dog like this? is he don't like the food? how can i stop this from happening in the future?

Comment: I suspect this is really two questions; why does the dog sometimes leave his food, and why is it trying to bite my housemate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he doesn't like it. My cat doesn't like kibble either, so I try to provide him with a varied diet. It does make him a very picky eater, though. When he is at his most trying, I tell myself that I wouldn't want to live on a diet of dry biscuits and water, either. Try to give your dog as varied a diet as possible.